# Big data Hadoop HDFS - put command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I'm unable to copy a file from local to HDFS. The command throws these errors.

[image]

Comment: Please can you paste the contents of the image as plain text? It helps other people to find this through search engines.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Windows path here, you have to escape the "\" or  use slash("/")

```
hadoop fs -put C:\\User\\Satya\\one.txt /user/local/hadoop/dirnew

// This is another way 
hadoop fs -put C:/User/Satya/one.txt /user/local/hadoop/dirnew
```

Also with Put command, you have to give only destination directory path. If you use `copyFromLocal`, it requires the destination file name along with directory.

Comment: Also note that this answer removes the unnecessary spaces between the two paths, present in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -copyfromLocal command instead of -put command.

```
hadoop fs -put < LFS path > < HDFS path >
hadoop fs -copyfromLocal < LFS path > < HDFS path >
```

Comment: This is incorrect - when the source is local, `copyFromLocal` and `put` are identical.